# Output utplsql test results to command line after Flyway migration

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, flyway

I've got the below in a migration script. How do I get the results output to the console after a flyway migration?

```
--Add New tests to the below
BEGIN
   utsuite.add ('AllTests');
   utpackage.ADD ('AllTests', 'ut_yard');
   utpackage.ADD ('AllTests', 'ut_kitchen');

   -- exec utplsql.runsuite ('AllTests');
   utplsql.runsuite ('AllTests');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call `utResult.show` which will display the output in the console.

See: http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/utresult.html

Comment: This looked like the correct answer, meaning no matter what happen in Flyway, and no matter where the output is kept or lost, the reports should persist in a table.  But when I execute the above test suite and then call utResult.show, it returns failure. :-( I think that utResult and test suites are incompatible/bug as otherwise this seems sensible.